# Is there a way to sync bitcoin core without verification?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, synchronization, bootstrap.dat

As the question asks, is there a way that one could sync the bitcoin client without verifying all the blocks. During IBD, downloading the blockchain isn't the bottleneck, what takes time is verifying all the blocks. I am aware that this is a very bad idea from the point of securing the bitcoin network however it has it's use cases. If I already have a node synced to the tip and want to run another node on a different machine it's pointless to sync from the network since I own both the machines. It's easier to just manually copy the blockchain to the other system and it's already synced?
Using something like `reindex` again takes a very long time since it verifies everything again.

Is there a way to do something like this?